# Nested hasManyThrough performance

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm experiencing an issue in my database layout. Basically, the layout is presented in the following way:

```
- Community
- - Each community has officers (Model `User`)
- - Each community has participants (Model `User`)

- Chat rooms (different section)
- - each chat room has participants (Model `User`)
- - each chat has officers, which are generated based on the participant's community's officers. This means: It's not hard-coded into a new table, instead, it should fetch the officers of the community, to which the participant (non-officer) belongs to.
```

My struggle is to achieve the last part, which is "officers can access". The query that I have right now is a complete mess, especially with the current server's plan. Considering that code is long, I'll make it straight forward:

```
- Fetch chat rooms
- - fetch participants of each chat room
- - - fetch communities of each participant 
- - - - fetch officers of each community 
- - - - add these officers to a main array in the model
- - - - remove any duplicated officers
```

Now, you can see that it's a very loose way of getting the result, and it costs a lot of performance. The only related model between officers and non-officers is `community`.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Learn about `JOIN`.

Comment: I did think about that, but I thought using the Eloquent models is "best practice"? Should I just go for Raw queries inside the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about creating new table `chat_room_community` where you are going to store chat rooms of community.
That table would have columns `community_id` `user_id` and `chat_room_id`.
Every time user joins/leaves chat room, add/remove record in this table.
You would also have to modify this new table whenever user joins new community or leaves one, but with this approach you can get all available chat rooms for officer with a simple query `(SELECT * FROM chat_room_community where community_id = ?)`

Comment: I actually thought of this, but then I'd need to update two tables. The table of `community_officers` when adding/removing an officer and the new `chat_room_community` table.  Isn't this redundant for the standards of eloquent?